# RequestMappingHandler is not mapping `/login` paths generated by Spring Security

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I think it might have something to do with this part of my configuration:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

I followed the Spring Security Tutorial here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html.  I'm unable to navigate to myApp/login, and it's not showing in the logs where all the other mappings are done.

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String package.controller.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/officeSearchResults],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView package.controller.OfficeController.search(java.lang.String)
...
```

The only difference between my code and the example is that I've built my view in .jsp instead of thymeleaf.  Here's the jsp, but I'm not sure it matters:

```
    <form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check"
        method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
            <input name="reset" type="reset" />
    </form>
```

UPDATE:

web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:jpaContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please offer suggestions or solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the web.xml entry where you have configured your dispatcher servlet? as well as the intercept urls mentioned in your app context?

Comment: I added the entire web.xml, but I'm not sure what you mean by the intercept urls.

Comment: Add your code for controller and your project directory structure.